# Intermittant fire of javascript code behind button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, button

Help. I have these buttons on a webpage, they are nested within an asp paginated gridview with updatepanel surrounding them. Do not be put of with all of that as everthing there works well however it is Button3 that is causing me problems.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Filter Jobs" CssClass="mybuttonblue" Style="width: 115px;" />
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Reset Filter" CssClass="mybuttonblue" Style="width: 115px;" OnClientClick="resetfilter();" />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Add New Job" CssClass="mybuttonblue" Style="width: 135px; float: right;" OnClick="btnNewJob" />
```

If you look at Button3, I have a OnClientClick which (as you know) on runtime converts to OnClick="" to run some javascript code.

The button is set to run "resetfilter()"... which is ..

```
<script>
    function resetfilter() {
        document.getElementById("filterID").value = "";
        document.getElementById("filterJobRef").value = "";
        document.getElementById("filterJobTitle").value = "";
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that sometimes when I press this button it fires this code, sometimes it does not. To know and test that I added the following.

```
<script>
    function resetfilter() {
        alert("fire");
        document.getElementById("filterID").value = "";
        document.getElementById("filterJobRef").value = "";
        document.getElementById("filterJobTitle").value = "";
    }
</script>
```

I have noticed that it will fire all of the time until an AJAX update has taken place on the updatepanel and then it will "sometimes" will not fire.

Any idea what is going on here?

Thanks

Comment: What is the AJAX update doing? What does it update? What is the result?

Comment: the update just reloads the page with new SQL for the grid. But only the grid data changes (because of the update panel). I have since found  more info. With the grid I put filter textboxes in the headers and it is only when I do a search using this then press RETURN in the textbox that is then the problem occurs. If I put text in the textbox and then click my trigger button it works. So the Ajax is doing something that is should not be doing. TBH ASP Gridbox is too bloated in my opinion.